# How to identify if a process is unique vs a coincidental same PID?

Tags: linux, pid

Having the ability to identify a PID for a process, let's say HTTPD for example, how can I determine later on, on that same server, if that PID/Process is still the original one ?

For instance, I could have an HTTPD process under PID **123**. A few minutes later that process could be terminated and a new HTTPD process created under (**coincidentally**) PID **123**. If I am monitoring a PID, I would not identify that HTTPD had ever been terminated.

What are the aspects I can rely to determine uniqueness on that are identifiable under `/proc/<PID>`

Ideally, a DTTM created, would be optimal, although I am not sure where this information is available in the kernel's reppresentation under `/prod/PID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at the creation date of the `/proc/PID` directory. It will be the same as the startup time. If the processus is destroyed and when it is re-run takes the same PID, it will change the start date (the directory date)

Comment: Good point. I forgot to consider the `proc/<pid>`'s directory date itself